# Part can't be found after the class name has changed

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I have multiple parts defined in my `application.e4xmi` file. These load up correctly.

I would now like one part to use a different class URI. I've now pointed the part to the new class URI and ran the application.

Here is the error I get.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-02-13 09:30:26.003
!MESSAGE Unable to load class 'com.example.ViewName' from bundle '3'
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.ViewName cannot be found by com.example_1.0.0.qualifier
```

I no longer use the `ViewName` class in the `application.e4xmi` file. This means that it must be getting the class URI from the cache. It is then unable to find the class and throws the error. I've tried `Synchronize` and `Launch an Eclipse application` in the product file as I thought that might update it but it has no effect. The original method I was using to update was to clear the cache but we can't have the users do this as they will lose their preferences.

What is the correct method of dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the `-clearPersistedState` flag in the 'Program arguments' section of the 'Arguments' tab of the Run Configuration. This will stop the Eclipse loading the persisted workbench.xmi from the previous run (this is in the .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder of the workspace).

Comment: How will it be handled if the user has an older version of the application and we give them a newer version with class changes? Does clear persisted state clear the whole cache (Like when ticking `Clear` in the run configuration) losing the previous positions of all views?

Comment: It clears the application model back to the model defined in the Application.e4xmi + fragments. So, yes, changes to position will be lost.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to this? I would like to use the same ids but with different classes and to maintain where it was positioned. This also means that if I decide to add any new views then the user must lose their layout settings?

Comment: I don't know of anything else.

Comment: I'm trying to think of a possible way of updating the model while keeping the users set layout as the users won't want to lose this. This is proving difficult.     
I've been looking at [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430090) and Nicolas mentions storing part of the layout to disk.     
 
I've now stored the `MApplication` to disk. I clear the cache and load this back in I'm having trouble with how I now compare the old `MApplication` to the new.
     
Do you have any ideas for how this might be done?

Comment: @Michael No, I don't have any ideas, my apps just use -clearPersistedState. However Eclipse 2019-03 due for release shortly does have a IWorkbench.PERSIST_STATE flag that might be of use - see [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.11/platform_isv.php). I have not used this.